# Text File to StringBuilder to DefaultListModel to JList Display

Tags: java, jlist, stringbuilder

I want to add strings from a file to a `StringBuilder` so that I can display the information as one `String`. How come the line `System.out.println(sb.toString());` isn't displaying in console? I cant tell if the code is working right, and it doesnt show any errors.

**File Example:**
LastName
FirstName
ID
Hometown
HomeState
Phone Number

`String input = textFieldLastName.getText()` is gathered from a JTextField

```
private String filename = "test.txt"
private static File file;
private static PrintWriter outputFile;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static JList list;
private static Scanner inputFile;

public void Read() throws IOException {

    if(file == null || filename.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("File not selected!");
    }else{
        inputFile = new Scanner(filename);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        while(inputFile.hasNext()){
            // Read the next name
            String ln = inputFile.nextLine();
            String input = textFieldLastName.getText(); 

            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(ln)){
                // Save friend information to variables
                sb.append(ln);
                        for(int i = 0; i <=5; i++){
                            sb.append(", " + inputFile.nextLine());
                        }
                listModel.addElement(sb.toString()); 
                System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
            }
        }
        list = new JList();
        list.setModel(listModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't display then it means it is not executed. So add more debug code to your class to track what part of the code is being executed.

Comment: @camickr tested it and it seems to stop at the `while(inputFile.hasNext())` because the `inputFile = new Scanner(filename);` goes to `filename` instead of a File.

I also dont have a `File file = new File(filename);` for the fix of `inputFile = new Scanner(file);`.

Comment: Sounds like you got it working now by provide a File for the Scanner.

Comment: Yeah, and now it works perfectly.